# Out of memory expection after migrating to maven latest version 3.3.9

Tags: java, maven

I have migrated maven version 3.0.1 to 3.3.9. when I am trying to do maven build I am getting the java heap size out of memory exception. If I increasing memory size to 8192 build will get success. But I donot want to increase my memory size and want to keep it as 4096. Is there any way to overcome this problem. Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: What goal cause the exception?  Consider adding the error message and stack trace from the output.

Comment: http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError

Comment: _Your_ error message and stack trace.  Currently you risk getting your question closed.